# Strange behavior in method_missing combined with instance_exec (ruby)

Tags: arrays, ruby

I am trying to make an instance of `Foo` execute some method or proc (whatever) if it or its `foo_instance` knows it. `foo_instance` is an instance of `Foo` that has some methods defined. I want, that when another instance of `Foo` doesn't respond to some method, if `foo_instance` does, that it will execute the proc in its instance:

```
class Foo
 attr_accessor :foo_instance  # this is an instance of Foo

   def get_proc(symbol)
   # ... a method that gets a proc (it has nothing to do with to_proc, and it is not binded to any thing, it only gets the code (as I'm only allowing to define new methods or accessors not directly, it doesn't matter)
   end


  def method_missing(symbol, *args, &block)
    throw NoMethodError unless self.foo_instance.respond_to? symbol
    some_proc = self.foo_instance.get_proc symbol
    self.instance_exec args, &some_proc
  end
end
```

For example, let's suppose foo_instance responds to some method called `foo_method`, that takes one argument, and it should be a number. And suppose, that, when we defined `foo_method`:

```
self.define_singleton_method :foo_method, & proc {|a| a + 1}
```

that's how I get to know the proc with `get_proc`, when I define the     method, I save it in a variable. anyway:

```
another_instance = Foo.new
another_instance.foo_method(1) # it goes to method_missing
```

when it gets to `method_missing`, by debugging I found that `args` is `[1]`, and it does:

```
self.instance_exec [1], proc { 'foo' }
```

and of course:

```
 TypeError: no implicit conversion of Fixnum into Array
```

The question is: what am I doing wrong? As `instance_exec` or `method_missing` should receive a `1`, not a `[1]`, and I'm not sending an array neither! I think it could be because of `*args` because it could be an array of args, but i'm not sure. I can't make it work.

Comment: Your block is trying to return the string `'foo'`? I can't reproduce the problem here. Can you come up with a minimal example of what you're trying to do here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is indeed because of the `*args` in the `method_missing` signature. This will save any arguments passed (except for the first one, which is the method name) and put them in an array (`1` -> `[1]`). To fix it, just use the `*` as a spat operator when calling `instance_exec`:

```
self.instance_exec *args, &some_proc
```

[How splatting works as explained in CRuby's repo](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/32674b167bddc0d737c38f84722986b0f228b44b/doc/syntax/calling_methods.rdoc#array-to-arguments-conversion)

Comment: Thanks! This was what I was missing.

Answer (score 0):

My understanding is that you wish to:

- create an instance `foo` of class `Foo`
- create one or more methods on `foo`'s singleton class
- when the symbol for one of `foo`'s singleton class methods, `m`, is sent to `boo`, a different instance of `Foo`, and `boo` does not respond to `m` (i.e., `m` is neither an instance method of `Foo` nor a method in `boo`'s singleton class), `method_missing` is to be used to send `m` to `foo`.

If this is correct, the accessor for `@foo_instance` must be in `Foo`'s singleton class, so it is available to all instances of `Foo`. We therefore begin as follows.

```
class Foo
  singleton_class.send(:attr_accessor, :foo_instance)
end

foo = Foo.new
   #=> #<Foo:0x007ff90c00f278> 
Foo.foo_instance = foo
Foo.foo_instance 
   #=> #<Foo:0x007ff90c00f278>
```

Now let's define a method on `foo`'s singleton class:

```
foo.define_singleton_method :foo_method, & proc {|a| a + 1}
foo.foo_method(3)
  #=> 4
```

and create another instance of `Foo`:

```
boo = Foo.new
  #=> #<Foo:0x007fcd63968858> 
boo.foo_method(1)
  #=> NoMethodError: undefined method `foo_method' for #<Foo:0x007fcd63968858>
```

When the last statement is executed, and `boo` does not respond to `foo_method`, we wish `foo_method`, with argument `1`, to be send to `foo`. We therefore can write `method_missing` as follows:

```
class Foo
  def method_missing(symbol, *args, &block)
    instance = self.class.foo_instance
    raise NoMethodError unless instance.respond_to? symbol
    instance.send(symbol, *args, &block) 
  end
end
```

Now

```
boo.foo_method(1)
  #=> 2
```